# Embedded Python still looking for debug symbols even with _DEBUG undefined

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2017, vtk, python-embedding

I'm trying to embed Python in a C++ application, and I need it to run as a release build, as I am only interested in debugging the C++ code. Also, I do not have the `_d` debug versions of all libraries I need. I am using Python 3.7.0, in MSVC 2017 with C++11, the library I don't have debug symbols for is VTK, which I installed through a wheel file supplied by my employer. If I try to build the Python wrapper myself I get another load of issues, so I am unable to build the debug files. If I run in Debug mode, I am unable to import the library, whereas if I run in Release, I get further issues:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF90841DBC9 (python37_d.dll) in PythonEmbedding.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000025.
```

The C++ code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pIntrospector = NULL;

    if (PyVtk_InitIntrospector(pIntrospector) == OK)
    {
        printf("Initialization succeeded\n");
    }

    vtkObjectBase *pConeSource = NULL;

    if (PyVtk_CreateVtkObject(pIntrospector, "vtkConeSource", pConeSource) == OK)
    {
        printf("Object creation succeeded\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int PyVtk_InitIntrospector(
    PyObject *pIntrospector)
{
    /* Activating virtual environment */
#ifdef _DEBUG 
    // For Visual Studio debug builds
    const wchar_t *sPyHome = L"venv-dbg";
#else
    // For release builds
    const wchar_t *sPyHome = L"venv";
#endif
    Py_SetPythonHome(sPyHome);

    /* Initializing Python environment and setting PYTHONPATH. */
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nimport os");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append( os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) )");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import importlib.machinery as m");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(m.all_suffixes())");

    /* Decode module from its name. Returns error if the name is not decodable. */
    PyObject *pIntrospectorModuleName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("Introspector");
    if (pIntrospectorModuleName == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode module name\n");
        return PYTHON_INTROSPECTION_STRING_DECODE_ERROR;
    }

    /* Imports the module previously decoded. Returns error if the module is not found. */
    PyObject *pIntrospectorModule = PyImport_Import(pIntrospectorModuleName);
    if (pIntrospectorModule == NULL)
    {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"Introspector\"\n");
        Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModuleName);
        return PYTHON_INTROSPECTION_MODULE_LOAD_ERROR;
    }

    /* Looks for the Introspector class in the module. If it does not find it, returns and error. */
    PyObject* pIntrospectorClass = PyObject_GetAttrString(pIntrospectorModule, "Introspector");
    if (pIntrospectorClass == NULL || !PyCallable_Check(pIntrospectorClass))
    {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find class \"Introspector\"\n");
        if (pIntrospectorClass != NULL)
        {
            Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorClass);
        }
        Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModuleName);
        Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModule);
        return PYTHON_INTROSPECTION_CLASS_NOT_FOUND_ERROR;
    }

    /* Instantiates an Introspector object. If the call returns NULL there was an error
       creating the object, and thus it returns error. */
    pIntrospector = PyObject_CallObject(pIntrospectorClass, NULL);
    if (pIntrospector == NULL)
    {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
        {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Introspector instantiation failed\n");
        Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModuleName);
        Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModule);
        Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorClass);
        return PYTHON_INTROSPECTION_OBJECT_CREATION_ERROR;
    }

    /* Decreasing reference to local data. */
    Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModuleName);
    Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorModule);
    Py_DECREF(pIntrospectorClass);
    return OK;
}
```

I have not added the code to the `PyVtk_CreateVtkObject` function as it won't enter it, but if I do not add the calls after `PyVtk_InitIntroepsctor` it won't give the aforementioned error. Finally, if I `import Introspector` in the Python interpreter myself, it works fine.

Is there a solution to either run it in Debug or Release? I cannot wrap my head around it...

P.S.: I already tried to use Boost::Python, I have two issues open on it as it is giving me problems as well.

**Update 1**: In particular, the excpetion is thrown when I do this:

```cpp
PyObject *pIntrospectorModule = PyImport_Import(pIntrospectorModuleName);
```

**Update 2**: I have further scoped down the issue to this: whenever I import the `vtk` package from within the embedded interpreter, it throws the Access Violation on this code:

```cpp
// Add special attribute __vtkname__
PyObject *s = PyString_FromString(classname);
PyDict_SetItemString(pytype->tp_dict, "__vtkname__", s);
Py_DECREF(s); // <-- In particular on this Py_DECREF
```

If I try to import anything else, there is no issue, it seems.